# How do I get IIS to direct traffic to other binded directory

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion-8

I have two sites configured on my IIS 7 server. One is the default web site and the other we will call www.othersite.com. The default web site runs a few different Applications running ASP.NET and the other site is a ColdFusion 8 web site.

The default site is configured to pull from the default web location at C:\inetpub\wwwroot while the other is set to pull from C:\sites\othersite.

The bindings are set to send all unassigned traffic to the Default Web Site, but www.othersite.com is set to a specific IP address. This is the same as I have it on other servers, which work perfectly well, but for some reason when I load www.othersite.com it is looking for its files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot instead of C:\sites\othersite even though the physical path is clearly defined in the basic settings.

Anyone have any idea why this might be and how I can get it to point to the proper directory?

Comment: You should be able to use host headers.  IIS allows you to set a site to respond to a specific request, i.e. coming via www.mysite.co.za or www.mysite.com, etc.

Comment: Yes, the host headers are already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS >> Bindings, you can see a place to put in "Host name".  Leaving blank will result in all traffic to IP or host, but by specifying a host name (www.othersite.com) will direct traffic to that dir/site.

Comment: Yes, I have the host name specified in the bindings for www.othersite.com as well as the IP address. It's still pointing to the default web site folder.

Comment: You have all the necessary DNS / host specified, i.e. you are trying to get to the site by typing "www.othersite.com" in the browser.  Sorry if I am asking the obvious - but trying to eliminate issues.

Comment: Yes, the DNS is specified. No problem on asking the obvious - best to rule that out first.